# Is Firestore Geo query officially available for Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am planning to recreate my native iOS and Android app to Flutter. I need like the documentation in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries#web_1) for native firebase development

I already read Flutter Fire documentation in [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) but I can't find it. Am I missing something? Sorry I am new in Flutter

I need the official one

Comment: Are you looking for this [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/geo_firestore_flutter) or [this one](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire)?

Comment: @JohnMichaelGelilio thanks John, but both of them are not official right? Firestore has official method to query based on geohash on native Android and iOS in here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries#web_1 . but sadly it seems it is not available on Flutter, it seems I have to use method channel in Flutter to get the data from native at this point in time